# Rally SDK 2.1 App Settings Multi Select Value not Preserved

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

When defining a getSettingsFields method I am attempting to use a multi select combobox:

```
getSettingsFields: function() {
    return [
        {
            name: 'Field',
            xtype: 'rallyfieldcombobox',
            model: 'portfolioitem/feature',
        },
        {
            name: 'RefinedStates',
            xtype: 'rallyattributecombobox',
            model: 'portfolioitem/feature',
            multiSelect: true,
            field: 'State',
        }
    ];
}
```

The single select combo box is working as expected and the value is preserved when saved, however the multi select values are not preserved. I've tried manually calling this.setValue(['possible_value']) in the combobox's ready function but that didn't seem to do it either. Any insight into a possible solution would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with setValue it seems there is some timing issue with multi select listeners. I tried setting the value in activate, render, ready, and a number of other listeners and had no luck initially, but eventually I tried ready with a setTimeout and it worked. Not ideal as it likely creates a race condition, but for this app I'm hoping users aren't messing with the settings too often so the occurrence of a bug should be rare